# closing the current popup and redirecting to the parent window

Tags: javascript

In JS I am using :

```
window.open('index.php?module=Contacts&action=UD_lookupemailtemplates&tempmode=userdefined&temp_url='+encodeURIComponent(temp_php_url),'emailtemplate','top=100,left=200,height=400,width=500,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,menubar=no,addressbar=no,status=yes')
```

To open a small window which has few links.
Now on the click on any one link an id will be attached to the a url and then I used this :

```
window.document.location.href = url;
```

This is also in JS. what this does is that it changes the contents of the small popup window but I need it to close the popup window and open this url in the main parent window from where the popup was created.
 Is that possible ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose

```
var popup_window = window.open(...);
```

For closing this use

```
popup_window.close();
```

and to redirect the parent windows

```
window.parent.location.href = url;
```

Answer (score 1):

To close a popup that you opened, store the return value from `window.open`:

```
var popup = window.open(...);
```

Then, you can use:

```
popup.close();
```

I'm not clear based on your question where the URL variable is stored (in which window), but you can reference window variables in the popup via `popup.variableName`.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to redirect parent window using

```
window.opener.location.href = "http://url.com";
```

and than close the current (popup) window

```
window.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Personaly I don't like pop up windows instead of that maybe yo can do the following:

You can open an overlay DIV that you can populate with data from "index.php?module=Contacts..." using AJAX and make links inside of that DIV that way so that by clicking them you close that overlay DIV and redirect page to what you want...